# How seeking ffplay or pipe from ffmpeg to ffplay

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

my goal is to check the file 10 minutes after the start. This is my script.

```
ffplay.exe -f lavfi "amovie=input.mov,showvolume=b=4:w=640:h=96"
```

If I add seeking, something like -ss 600, the file always starts from the beginning,

anyone know workaround? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways of doing this:

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.mov:sp=600,showvolume=b=4:w=640:h=96"
```

`sp` is option `seek_point` - will seek from nearest keyframe before seek point.

---

```
ffplay -f lavfi "amovie=input.mov,atrim=600,showvolume=b=4:w=640:h=96"
```

Apply a (a)trim filter.